# Rotating wallpapers of varying sizes

Tags: macos

I have several desktop backgrounds that I would like to rotate between, but one of them is vertically oriented. If I leave the backgrounds set to "Fill Screen," it chops off the top and the bottom of the vertical wallpaper, and that's not okay.

I'd like to know if there is a way to tell individual wallpapers to "Fit to Screen" while having others "Fill Screen," "Center," and et cetera.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No you can't, but you could edit the vertically oriented wallpaper to match the aspect ratio of your monitor.